# Anonymous User Can't Delete file from ftp

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, rhel6, centos6.5

I've created a new directory in /var/ftp with the name uploads

the owner and group of this directory is ftp

the permissions are set to 777.

Content of my vsftpd.conf file

```
anonymous_enable=YES

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

anon_upload_enable=YES

anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog

xferlog_std_format=YES

nopriv_user=ftpsecure

ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

SELINUX permissions are -

```
allow_ftpd_anon_write --> on
allow_ftpd_full_access --> on
```

I can upload files in directory but can't delete files through FTP

Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: I've created a user and have tried to delete files through that too. I can easily connect to ftp but I'm unable to delete files

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [manpage](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) of vsftpd and use the option:
`anon_other_write_enable=YES`

Comment: I have disabled SElinux. Still I can't delete files :(